# Is result of train/test split the same on different machines with set random_state?

Tags: machine-learning, random, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I want to reduce randomness when training models on different machines and I was wondering if setting param `random_state` in sklearn `rain_test_split` gives always the same results. Is it dependent on system or not?

So when ruining this code on computer 1, will I get exactly the same split on computer 2?

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such guarantee. The produced results may vary with the OS and the version of the low level libraries installed on a system. 
You may go through this discussion to get a better idea -  [Random_state produces different results on different operating systems #153](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/153)